# templateUrl - Angular dynamic directive loads more than once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to have a directive which inherits properties from its parent scope load one of three different templates depending on the property of `scope.stnPage`. Unfortunately, I get this warning:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
>   WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.

I've commented out everything from the parent controller and it still does this. I've set `scope` to `true` and it still does this. I've narrowed the answer down to templateUrl as the root of the problem.

This is the element I'm using:

```
<preset-stations page="page1"></preset-stations>
```

This is my code on the directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('presetStations', ['$state', '$interval', '$parse', '$compile', function($state, $interval, $parse, $compile){

    var presets = {
        //array
    };      

    function getContentUrl(x){
        var url = 'public/javascripts/presets' + x + '.html';
        return url;
    };

    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs){
        //stuff i've commented out
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: true,
        link: linker,
        templateUrl: function(el, attrs){
            return getContentUrl(attrs.page);
        }
    };  
}]);
```

This doesn't work, but this does:

```
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: true,
        link: linker,
        templateUrl: function(el, attrs){
            return 'public/templates/presetspage1.html;
        }
    };
```

I've seen the following on other pages related to dynamic templates in directives.  I've tried variations of this but it has not worked. Is the solution here?

```
    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.html(getTemplate(scope.content)).show();
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    };

    function getTemplate(){
        // stuff happens here
    }
```

This was the results in dev tools network:

[image]

Comment: do you have any other library in page that might be over riding `XMLHttpRequest` or any angular httpIntercecptors that might set requests to synchronous? That warning shouldn't come from any angular requests alone

Comment: Like what for instance? I've removed some of the dependencies I've injected in the controller and the directive and the same problem persists.

Comment: Any sort of third party ajax library for example.

Comment: I've narrowed the problem down to templateUrl. When I have a static url it works, but not a dynamic url

Comment: so when it is `dynamic` where are requests actually going? Look in dev tools network. This is a really wierd issue unless code shown is different than what you are using live

Comment: You could try this. if probably init with undefined attrs.page   
templateUrl: function(el, attrs){
    if (!attrs.page) {
        return;
}

            return getContentUrl(attrs.page);
        }

Comment: I've added a screenshot to the dev tools network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of a hack, but it works: I made three directives which share the same functions between a factory and I did this in the DOM:

```
        <div ng-if="stnPage === 'page1'">
            <preset-station-one></preset-station-one>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="stnPage === 'page2'">
            <preset-station-two></preset-station-two>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="stnPage === 'page3'">
            <preset-station-three></preset-station-three>
        </div>
```

I know this goes against the D.R.Y. principle, but I shared functions as much as I possibly could.